# Badge symbol in notification is of the site you're on, not where badge was earned

Tags: feature-request, badges, design, notifications

It's so cool that the notification reminds you of the colour of badge you've earned. But I am a little puzzled by the symbols:

[image: meta]
[image: workplace]
[image]

Is it feasible to use the symbol from the earned site? At the moment it uses the symbol from the site I happen to be on (as you can see by looking to the left of the dropdown in each case.)

Comment: I imagine it's the same reason badges for all accounts are the same in your user profile. Hard to style each one differently. See: [Unique Badge Icons in Summary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222452/unique-badge-icons-in-summary)

Comment: @mhlester: it is a pretty close duplicate, I'd say.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree. The profile needs to show all the badges from all the sites. That's a different task from "today's badges" so perf is less of an issue.

Comment: Using the icon from the "earned site" may be infeasible/undesirable since that would mean cross-loading icons; in that case, please just use the default circles!

Comment: @mhlester: Not quite; the (left part of the) top-bar is supposed to look&feel the same everywhere, so why use different icons at all? The defaults (cf beta sites) would do and, in particular, not interfere with the site style (which is the biggest counter-argument in the question you link).

Comment: "How can I sell myself" sounds so much like an Arqade title, it took me a while to realize the problem wasn't that it was displaying the Workplace icon instead of the Arqade icon.

Comment: Any official statements from SE whether this will/might (not) ever be fixed?

Comment: @ByteCommander There are no plans to change this behavior. I'm leaving the feature request open, though, since well... it's a legit request.

Comment: @Adam so having an  accepted answer does not remove this from the radar?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Eh? Why would it?

Comment: @Adam because usually having accepted answer means "OK, this issue is resolved", so I thought your filter might omit those, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+closed%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0+is%3Aq

Comment: No, I accepted Caleb's answer because I agree, making the badge icons just be dots would be less confusing than using the actively-wrong icon, without taking the (I don't know how convinced I am) performance hit of getting the right icon for every badge you're being notified of. But this isn't status-completed and if accepting answers made requests closed, what need would we have of those pink tags? (Maybe @AdamLear can get me a pink status-review?)

Comment: The accepted answer has no effect on how we consider requests, @KateGregory. status-review, on the other hand, would be a lie since the request's not actually under active review and increase the odds of it not being revisited later. :)

Comment: Thanks @Adam, wasn't sure about that. Well, back to waiting... ;)

Comment: @AdamLear Since the frontend is under rework these days, anyway, any news on this?

Comment: @Raphael I don't think this is changing as part of the current frontend work. It's more of a back end issue - since we render the dropdown on the site you're on, it picks up that site's styles. Favicons, on the other hand, come from a shared sprite.

Comment: Seems that this is happening again, and coincided with another episode of rep not being reported: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316338/332286

Comment: @DarkCygnus it never stopped happening, it's how things are. I doubt it's related to missing rep.

Comment: Another problem is that some sites [such as Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/510296/rob) use three different shapes as well as different colors for the badges. Using a generic shape (circles, squares or diamonds) is one possibility, another answer is to reuse the site's favicon in the left column and resize it (using CSS) to approximately 65% - in some cases that duplicates what would (should) be presented and in no cases would it be confusing.

Comment: I still can not imagine why it is so hard to use the form of badge from where you earned it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I can understand why this ended up this way given per-site theming and not wanting to load the sprite sets for every site when loading any one site, but still this is very counter-intuitive and [keeps coming up](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6005/30).

**I propose** making the badge icons in this particular menu where many site badges sit side by side just be the colored dots with no site-local sprites applied.

Answer (score 34):

After what turned out to be a somewhat excessively long delay, version 1.16 of my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script now includes a client-side CSS patch to fix this.

Basically, what I did was add some custom styles to override the default styling for the badges in the achievements menu:

```css
.achievements-dialog .badge1,
.achievements-dialog .badge2,
.achievements-dialog .badge3 {
    height: 8px !important;
    width: 8px !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    margin: 0px 2px 4px;
}
.achievements-dialog .badge1 { background: #ffcc00 !important }
.achievements-dialog .badge2 { background: #c5c5c5 !important }
.achievements-dialog .badge3 { background: #cc9966 !important }
```

(The reason for all those ugly `!important` tags is that some SE sites, like Meta.SE, use `!important` in their site badge styles, so I have to use it too in order to consistently override the site styles.)

The result looks like this (on Academia.SE, which has a pretty distinct badge style):

[image: Screenshot]

Note that the custom dots are a little bit bigger than the standard ones used e.g. in the top bar here on meta, since I felt the standard dots looked too small in the menu.

Comment: The SOUPinator strikes again -- great work, thanks!

Comment: I use Greasemonkey on FF. I know I have seen autoupdates before and when I forced it to check for updates, it found and installed them without problem. Maybe because I "require secure updates"?

Comment: @Raphael: Not sure if that's it, the update URLs *do* use HTTPS. But I'll keep it in mind and see if I can reproduce it. Thanks!

Comment: Saw this same problem yesterday (earned a badge in math.SE, saw in in academia.SE and was puzzled by the birret for the badge).

Was using Fedora 22 up to date with firefox-39.0.3-1.fc22.x86_64, date was 2015-08-19.