# Top-bar notification drop-down always uses badge icons from current site

Tags: bug, badges, notifications, top-bar, icons

I was surprised to see that I earned a Sci-Fi badge on CS:

[image]

I reproduced this on other sites; the drop-down always uses the icons from current site C, not those from the site E the badge was earned on.

Ideally, the icons from E should be used. If that is infeasible, please use the default circles. Using icons from C is definitely confusing.

Comment: @mhlester Arg... you can search the Meta, but never find anything. :/

Comment: isn't that the truth?

Comment: Meta Searching is a Master Level Skill which can only be taught by Tim Stone.

Comment: @animuson: I assume he lives alone in a swamp of duplicate questions, impossible to reach without the rare Force of SQL?

Comment: [Workaround by userscript available](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233538/156248).