# Different notification colour for notifications relating to other sites on the Stack Exchange network

Tags: feature-request, notifications, top-bar

I'm subscribed and relatively active in a few communities in the Stack Exchange network. It is a nice feature of the site that notifications (both "message" and "rep" ones) are collected from all the networks one is subscribed to, eliminating the need to have to visit each network separately to find out if you have any new notifications.

However, it would also be useful for me to be able to tell visually if these notifications are exclusively from other network sites than the one I'm currently visiting. For instance, if I visit *[TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)*, and I only have notifications pending from Stack Overflow, I would like at a glance to know that while I have notifications waiting, none of them are actually relating to the current (i.e. *TeX - LaTeX*) site.

A case scenario would be if I generally get a lot of notifications from Stack Overflow and not from *TeX - LaTeX*, and I've just asked a question on *TeX - LaTeX* regarding my thesis, and I'm expecting an answer and check on *TeX - LaTeX* periodically. I would like to not have to check every time I see a notification (which is more likely to be from Stack Overflow and a distraction from the current task) and only catch my eye properly if the notification originates from within *TeX - LaTeX*.

Perhaps this could be done with a more faded-out version of the icons currently used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notifications in the top bar are the same across the network, and they are almost certainly computed once, not per-site, as you move about the network.  Adding "localization" to the notification would thus involve a lot more computing -- which might sound trivial, but SO gets [49 million unique views/month](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com).

Even the badge notifications, which are per-site and not per-user, [don't get per-site styling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233517/162102), and that would involve less work than what you're suggesting.

You might want to instead keep a tab open to the "responses" tab on your TeX user page and refresh it from time to time.  If anything lights up there, you have local responses.