# Notification links sometimes showing in wrong color on some sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When you check your notifications, they can come up the wrong color. This is brand new, and it depends on the site. This is on ELU:

---

[image: ELU colors]

---

Whereas this is on MSE (or SO):

---

[image: MSE colors]

---

and this is on Mi Yodeya:

---

[image: MY colors]

---

It’s also been reported to happen from a cell phone, where some links are red and others blue: "seems random" they said.

So it looks like some of the site overrides are now leaking through the CSS where they never used to.

Comment: Related: [Badge symbol in notification is of the site you're on, not where badge was earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233517/312043)

Comment: Just noticed this too. I got the Civic Duty badge on MSO and noticed that it turned all of my achievements listed below it a reddish-orange color when viewing from RPG.SE. The color of the items under Achievements alternately seems blue when viewed from some other sites.

Comment: Same is true for the "Communities" tab, on certain sites (seems most common on certain meta sites).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This got fixed this afternoon. Thanks for pointing it out! In our effort to improve our frontend so things like this are less likely to slip through the cracks, something like this slipped through the cracks. THE IRONY!

Comment: Less likely isn't zero. :)